Wikipedia API: how to parse content of(*) text into JSON?
I'm making a request to the MediaWiki API to get information about a specific page, but I'm having trouble parsing the content of the revisions. Here's an example request I'm using:
http://yugioh.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=Red_Dragon_Archfiend
This is the output of the request :
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "warnings": {
    "main": {
      "*": "Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at \u003Chttps://lists.wikimedia.org/postorius/lists/mediawiki-api-announce.lists.wikimedia.org/\u003E for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes."
    },
    "revisions": {
      "*": "Because \"rvslots\" was not specified, a legacy format has been used for the output. This format is deprecated, and in the future the new format will always be used."
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "normalized": [
      {
        "from": "Red_Dragon_Archfiend",
        "to": "Red Dragon Archfiend"
      }
    ],
    "pages": {
      "95272": {
        "pageid": 95272,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Red Dragon Archfiend",
        "revisions": [
          {
            "contentformat": "text/x-wiki",
            "contentmodel": "wikitext",
            "*": "{{For|the card|the character|Red Dragon Archfiend (character)|the [[archetype]]|Red Dragon Archfiend (archetype)}}\n{{Unofficial name|Arabic|Bulgarian|Croatian|Greek|Thai|Vietnamese|Turkish}}\n{{Unofficial lore|Chinese}}\n\n{{CardTable2\n| image                    = RedDragonArchfiend-SDCK-EN-UR-1E.png\n| ar_name                  = تنين الشر الأحمر\n| bg_name                  = Червен Дракон Архдемон\n| zh_name                  = chineese\n| hr_name                  = Nadzloduh Crveni Zmaj\n| fr_name                  = Dragon Rouge Archdémon\n| de_name                  = Rotdrachen-Erzunterweltler\n| el_name                  = Κόκκινος Αρχιδαιμονικός Δράκος\n| it_name                  = Arcidemone Drago Rosso\n| ko_name                  = chineese\n| pt_name                  = Dragão Vermelho Arquidemônio\n| es_name                  = Dragón Rojo Archidemonio\n| sv_name                  = Den Röda Draken Arkdemonen\n| th_name                  = เรด เดม่อน ดราก้อน\n| tr_name                  = Kırmızı Ejder Şeytanı\n| vi_name                  = Xích Quỷ Long\n| ja_name                  = レッド・デーモンズ・ドラゴン\n| romaji_name              = Reddo Dēmonzu Doragon\n| trans_name               = Red Daemon's Dragon\n| attribute                = DARK\n| type                     = Dragon\n| type2                    = Synchro\n| type3                    = Effect\n| level                    = 8\n| atk                      = 3000\n| def                      = 2000\n| passcode                 = 70902743\n| materials                = 1 Tuner + 1+ non-Tuner monsters\n| effect_types             = Trigger, Trigger, Condition\n| ocg                      = Unlimited\n| adv                      = Unlimited\n| trad                     = Unlimited\n| lore                     = 1 [[Tuner monster|Tuner]] + 1+ non-Tuner [[Monster Card|monsters]]\u003Cbr /\u003EAfter [[damage calculation]], if this card [[attack]]ed an opponent's [[Defense Position]] monster: [[Destroy]] all Defense Position monsters your opponent [[control]]s. [[Once per turn]], during your [[End Phase]]: Destroy all other monsters you control that did not declare an attack this [[turn]]. This card must be [[face-up]] on the [[field]] to activate and to [[resolve]] this [[effect]].\n| fr_lore                  = 1 Syntoniseur + 1+ monstre non-Syntoniseur\u003Cbr /\u003EAprès le calcul des dommages, si cette carte a attaqué un monstre en Position de Défense de l'adversaire : détruisez tous les monstres en Position de Défense contrôlés par votre adversaire. Une fois par tour, durant votre End Phase : détruisez tous les autres monstres que vous contrôlez qui n'ont pas déclaré d'attaque ce tour. Cette carte doit être face recto sur le Terrain pour activer et résoudre cet effet.\n| de_lore                  = 1 Empfänger + 1+ Nicht-Empfänger-Monster\u003Cbr /\u003ENach der Schadensberechnung, falls diese Karte ein Monster eines Gegners in Verteidigungsposition angegriffen hat: Zerstöre alle Monster in Verteidigungsposition, die dein Gegner kontrolliert. Einmal pro Spielzug, während deiner End Phase: Zerstöre alle anderen Monster, die du kontrollierst und die in diesem Spielzug keinen Angriff deklariert haben. Diese Karte muss offen auf dem Spielfeld liegen, um diesen Effekt zu aktivieren und aufzulösen.\n| it_lore                  = 1 Tuner + 1+ mostri non-Tuner\u003Cbr /\u003EDopo il calcolo dei danni, se questa carta ha attaccato un mostro in Posizione di Difesa dell'avversario: distruggi tutti i mostri in Posizione di Difesa controllati dal tuo avversario. Una volta per turno, durante la tua End Phase: distruggi tutti gli altri mostri che controlli che non hanno dichiarato un attacco in questo turno. Questa carta deve essere scoperta sul Terreno per attivare e risolvere questo effetto.\n| pt_lore                  = 1 Regulador + 1+ monstros não-Reguladores\u003Cbr /\u003EDepois do cálculo de dano, se este card atacou um monstro do oponente em Posição de Defesa: destrua todos os monstros em Posição de Defesa que seu oponente controla. Uma vez por turno, durante sua Fase Final: destrua todos os outros monstros que você controla que não declararam um ataque neste turno. Este card deve estar com a face para cima no campo para ativar e resolver este efeito.\n| es_lore                  = 1 Cantante + 1+ monstruos que no sean Cantantes\u003Cbr /\u003EDespués del cálculo de daño, si esta carta atacó un monstruo en Posición de Defensa del adversario: destruye todos los monstruos en Posición de Defensa que controle tu adversario. Una vez por turno, durante tu End Phase: destruye todos los demás monstruos que controles que este turno no declararon un ataque. Esta carta debe estar boca arriba en el Campo para activar y resolver este efecto.\n| ja_lore                  = chineese。\n| ko_lore                  = chineese \n| en_sets                  = \n{{Card set|lang=en|\nCT05-EN002; Collectible Tins 2008 Wave 1; Secret Rare\nTDGS-EN041; The Duelist Genesis; Ultra Rare\nTDGS-EN041; The Duelist Genesis; Ultimate Rare\nCT07-EN025; Collectible Tins 2010 Wave 2; Super Rare\nTU06-EN008; Turbo Pack: Booster Six; Rare\nLC5D-EN069; Legendary Collection 5D's Mega Pack; Common\nLC5D-EN069; Legendary Collection 5D's Mega Pack; Ultra Rare\nHSRD-EN023; High-Speed Riders; Common\nGFP2-EN182; Ghosts From the Past: The 2nd Haunting; Ghost Rare\nSDCK-EN045; Structure Deck: The Crimson King; Ultra Rare\n}}\n| fr_sets                  = \n{{Card set|lang=fr|\nCT05-FR002; Collectible Tins 2008 Wave 1; Secret Rare\nTDGS-FR041; The Duelist Genesis; Ultra Rare\nTDGS-FR041; The Duelist Genesis; Ultimate Rare\nCT07-FR025; Collectible Tins 2010 Wave 2; Super Rare\nTU06-FR008; Turbo Pack: Booster Six; Rare\nLC5D-FR069; Legendary Collection 5D's Mega Pack; Common\nLC5D-FR069; Legendary Collection 5D's Mega Pack; Ultra Rare\nHSRD-FR023; High-Speed Riders; Common\nGFP2-FR182; Ghosts From the Past: The 2nd Haunting; Ghost Rare\nSDCK-FR045; Structure Deck: The Crimson King; Ultra Rare\n}}\n| de_sets                  = \n{{Card set|lang=de|\nCT05-DE002; Collectible Tins 2008 Wave 1; Secret Rare\nTDGS-DE041; The Duelist Genesis; Ultra Rare\nTDGS-DE041; The Duelist Genesis; Ultimate Rare\nCT07-DE025; Collectible Tins 2010 Wave 2; Super Rare\nTU06-DE008; Turbo Pack: Booster Six; Rare\nAC11-DE006; Yu-Gi-Oh! Advent Calendar; Ultra Rare\nLC5D-DE069; Legendary Collection 5D's Mega Pack; Common\nLC5D-DE069; Legendary Collection 5D's Mega Pack; Ultra Rare\nHSRD-DE023; High-Speed Riders; Common\nGFP2-DE182; Ghosts From the Past: The 2nd Haunting; Ghost Rare\nSDCK-DE045; Structure Deck: The Crimson King; Ultra Rare\n}}\n| it_sets                  = \n{{Card set|lang=it|\nCT05-IT002; Collectible Tins 2008 Wave 1; Secret Rare\nTDGS-IT041; The Duelist Genesis; Ultra Rare\nTDGS-IT041; The Duelist Genesis; Ultimate Rare\nCT07-IT025; Collectible Tins 2010 Wave 2; Super Rare\nTU06-IT008; Turbo Pack: Booster Six; Rare\nLC5D-IT069; Legendary Collection 5D's Mega Pack; Common\nLC5D-IT069; Legendary Collection 5D's Mega Pack; Ultra Rare\nHSRD-IT023; High-Speed Riders; Common\nGFP2-IT182; Ghosts From the Past: The 2nd Haunting; Ghost Rare\nSDCK-IT045; Structure Deck: The Crimson King; Ultra Rare\n}}\n| pt_sets                  = \n{{Card set|lang=pt|\nLC5D-PT069; Legendary Collection 5D's Mega Pack; Common\nLC5D-PT069; Legendary Collection 5D's Mega Pack; Ultra Rare\nHSRD-PT023; High-Speed Riders; Common\nOP10-PT032; OTS Tournament Pack 10; Common\nGFP2-PT182; Ghosts From the Past: The 2nd Haunting; Ghost Rare\nSDCK-PT045; Structure Deck: The Crimson King; Ultra Rare\n}}\n| sp_sets                  = \n{{Card set|lang=sp|\nCT05-SP002; Collectible Tins 2008 Wave 1; Secret Rare\nTDGS-SP041; The Duelist Genesis; Ultra Rare\nTDGS-SP041; The Duelist Genesis; Ultimate Rare\nCT07-SP025; Collectible Tins 2010 Wave 2; Super Rare\nTU06-SP008; Turbo Pack: Booster Six; Rare\nLC5D-SP069; Legendary Collection 5D's Mega Pack; Common\nLC5D-SP069; Legendary Collection 5D's Mega Pack; Ultra Rare\nHSRD-SP023; High-Speed Riders; Common\nGFP2-SP182; Ghosts From the Past: The 2nd Haunting; Ghost Rare\nSDCK-SP045; Structure Deck: The Crimson King; Ultra Rare\n}}\n| jp_sets                  = \n{{Card set|lang=jp|\nWJMP-JP010; Weekly Shōnen Jump 2008, Issue 18 promotional card; Secret Rare\nTDGS-JP041; The Duelist Genesis; Ultra Rare\nTDGS-JP041; The Duelist Genesis; Ultimate Rare\nMFC1-JP002; Monster Figure Collection promotional cards; Duel Terminal Normal Parallel Rare\nDE03-JP016; Duelist Edition Volume 3; Ultra Rare\nSPHR-JP023; Booster SP: Highspeed Riders; Common\nSPHR-JP023; Booster SP: Highspeed Riders; Normal Parallel Rare\nLGB1-JP023; Legendary Gold Box; Normal Parallel Rare\nSD46-JPP01; Structure Deck: Pulse of the King Rumbling of Heaven and Earth Pack; Super Rare\nSD46-JPP01; Structure Deck: Pulse of the King Rumbling of Heaven and Earth Pack; Secret Rare\n}}\n| kr_sets                  = \n{{Card set|lang=kr|\nTDGS-KR041; The Duelist Genesis; Ultra Rare\nTDGS-KR041; The Duelist Genesis; Ultimate Rare\nSPHR-KR023; Booster SP: Highspeed Riders; Common\nSPHR-KR023; Booster SP: Highspeed Riders; Normal Parallel Rare\nLGB1-KR023; Legendary Gold Box; Normal Parallel Rare\nSD46-KRP01; Structure Deck: Pulse of the King Rumbling of Heaven and Earth Pack; Super Rare\nSD46-KRP01; Structure Deck: Pulse of the King Rumbling of Heaven and Earth Pack; Secret Rare\n}}\n| ygo_sets                 = \n'''[[Pack 49 (YGOO-BP)|Pack 49]]'''\n| vid                      = [[Yu-Gi-Oh! 5D's Tag Force 4]]\n| archseries               = \n* Red Dragon Archfiend (archetype)\n* Archfiend\n* Signer Dragon\n| related_to_archseries    = \n*/Assault Mode\n* Cosmic Synchro Monster\n* Duel Dragon\n* Greed (series)\n* Majestic\n* Signature move\n| m/s/t                    = \n* Destroys your opponent's Defense Position Monster Cards\n* Destroys your Monster Cards\n| summoning                = \n* 1+ non-Tuner Synchro Materials\n* Does not require specific Synchro Materials\n| sm_for                   = \n* Majestic Red Dragon\n* Red Nova Dragon\n| database_id              = 7735\n}}\n\n[[pl:Red Dragon Archfiend]]"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

The important part for me is the content within query.pages.revisions[0]["*"]. However, this content is in wikitext format and not JSON.
Is there a way to retrieve this field directly as JSON or another structured format? If not, what's the best approach to parse this content efficiently?
I've looked through the MediaWiki API documentation, but I couldn't find a solution that addresses this specific need.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Wikitext is inherently unstructured - it can be asolutely anything. You can parse wikitext with various tools to assist with extracting the data but we'll need to know what language you are using.

@smartse Im currently using javascript (node) and its also fine for me if it's JAVA

For the language its really not a blocking point for me as long as there is a simple way rather than using regex.
